# Converting worktree back to normal git structure

Tags: git

I converted a Perforce depot to a git repository by using a worktree approach (git-p4 did not work since it was lacking a lot of features). My converter does exactly what I need.

That means the git worktree hierarchy matches the Perforce depot. From here on I would like to use the "git way" by checking out a branch in the main directory. Is there any way how I can now go to this?

Is deleting the `./git/worktree` directory enough?

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve? Does something specific prevent you from checking out a branch?

Comment: No, but the branch exists in another directory than the work directory